# python pandas portfolio return

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I've got a dataframe with market data and one column dedicated to daily returns.
I'm having a hard time creating a portfolio to start at $100,000.00 in value, and compute its cumulative return through the life of the data series.

Ideally, I'd like to compute the 'portfolio' column using pandas but I'm having trouble doing so. See below target output. Thank you.

```
index    date      index  return  portfolio
0        19900101  2000   Nan     100000.00
1        19900102  2002   0.001   100100.00
2        19900103  2020   0.00899 100999.90 
3        19900104  2001  -0.00941 100049.49
```

Comment: Shouldn't you simply sum up the `return` column?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You can't sum the returns (assuming simple returns instead of log), they need to be compounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `cumprod`

```
df['P']=df['return'].add(1).fillna(1).cumprod()*100000
df
Out[843]: 
   index      date  index.1   return  portfolio             P
0      0  19900101     2000      NaN  100000.00  100000.00000
1      1  19900102     2002  0.00100  100100.00  100100.00000
2      2  19900103     2020  0.00899  100999.90  100999.89900
3      3  19900104     2001 -0.00941  100049.49  100049.48995
```

Some adjustments:

```
df=df.replace('Nan',np.nan)
df['return']=pd.to_numeric(df['return'])
```

Comment: is there a good resource to visualize what is happening in this formula? Specifically, multiplying our starting value for some reason causes a mental block in seeing the cumulative value be multiplied throughout.. as opposed to that constant... ty!

Comment: @antonio_zeus you mention the return , return is the percentage change from previous value (not the initial value )

Answer (score 3):

```
starting_value = 100000
df = df.assign(portfolio=(1 + df['return'].fillna(0)).cumprod().mul(starting_value))
>>> df
   index      date  index.1   return     portfolio
0      0  19900101     2000      NaN  100000.00000
1      1  19900102     2002  0.00100  100100.00000
2      2  19900103     2020  0.00899  100999.89900
3      3  19900104     2001 -0.00941  100049.48995
```

To visualize what is happening, `cumprod` is calculating compounded returns, e.g. `cum_r3 = (1 + r1) * (1 + r2) * (1 + r3)`.

```
>>> (1 + df['return'].fillna(0)).cumprod()
0    1.000000
1    1.001000
2    1.009999
3    1.000495
Name: return, dtype: float64
```